# MySQL Join based on IF

Tags: php, mysql, join, if-statement, conditional-statements

This situation involves 3 tables. 
items
videos
instructions

Each Item has a column 'entitytype' and a handle 'entityid' which is the corresponding id of a row in either table videos or table instructions. Unfortunately the name of the id's in these tables is urlid and textid respectively.

I would like to select an Item, and Join the data from either a row in videos or a row in instructions onto the selection based on what value 'entitytype' holds

This code is psuedo, I am new to MySQL and trying to find a means to convey my intentions

Here's my intuition thus far:

```
SELECT items.*, 
    IF(entitytype='video', 'videos', 'instructions') as detail_table,
    IF(entitytype='video', 'urlid', 'textid') as detail_id
FROM items
    JOIN (detail_table) ON (items.entityid=detail_table.detail_id)
WHERE itemid=something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join against both tables, and select the value you need using the IF.

```
SELECT items.yourcolumns,
    IF(items.entitytype='video', urlid, textid) as result_id
FROM items
    LEFT OUTER JOIN videos ON items.entityid=videos.urlid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN instructions ON items.entityid=instructions.textid
WHERE itemid=something
```

Your relational model is broken if a column's reference points to another table based on another columns value.

Better: have two extra tables: `items_to_video` and `items_to_instructions` which make a link where needed

#### Edit: after two minutes of lying in bed and not thinking about it, I thought about it. Offcourse.

```
 SELECT items.yourcolumns,
     urlid as result_id
 FROM items
     JOIN videos ON items.entityid=videos.urlid
 WHERE itemid=something AND items.entitytype='video'
UNION ALL
 SELECT items.yourcolumns,
     textid as result_id
 FROM items
     JOIN instructions ON items.entityid=instructions.textid
 WHERE itemid=something AND items.entitytype<>'video'
```

Comment: Why would I need the IF if I'm just going to try joining both tables anyway?

Comment: Because the IF auto-fills in the value that gets sent back to your code. Less data to transfer. You can work without the if, and send back both values, and have your code use the one it needs - less CPU usage for your database, more data to send. You can't "for each row, only join with one table", it would not be efficient in terms of data access.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Good to know. Let's see if this plays nice

Comment: Edited the answer: removed the table.* (usually bad style: name your columns) and removed the `'` around urlid and textid in the `IF`, since we are talking about columns, not the strings.

Comment: So I misunderstood what result_id would be. This does send back the name of the id field from the appropriate table, but I can deduce that from items.entitytype. What I would really like is to do only one JOIN, and JOIN based on items.entitytype. Is that possible?

Comment: Awesome. So, despite having two JOIN's in the FROM, I'm still making some savings because of the IF? Thanks for your help Konerak

Comment: @PandemoniumSyndicate: I slept and found yet another solution that only joins the elements you need, but at the cost of two scans of 'items'. I would still go with the first solution (one scan of items with a double join), but the second solution should also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can show the query dynamically with PHP, I think it may even gain performance.
It would be something like:

```
<?php
$detail_table = 'detail_table';
$detail_id = 'detail_id';

$sql = "SELECT items.*, 
    {$detail_table},
    {$detail_id}
FROM items
    JOIN {$detail_table} ON (items.entityid={$detail_table}.{$detail_id})
WHERE itemid=something";
```

By the way,
You can add joins with both table:

```
SELECT
    items.*,
    instructions.*,
    videos.*
FROM
    items
    LEFT JOIN videos ON (items.entityid=videos.detail_id)
    LEFT JOIN instructions ON (items.entityid=instructions.detail_id)
WHERE
    itemid=something
```

Comment: Problem is I don't know which of the two tables I'll be selecting from before the call, it's based on what value is in item.entitytype

Comment: OMG! Delete this answer... Konerak already answered the question

Comment: You can delete the answer yourself if you want, but it is not *wrong*, so there is no *real need* to.